# Python script API post request suddenly has stopped working

Tags: python, api, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
from woocommerce import API

url2 = "http://ssl.autovit.ro/api/open/account/adverts"
url4 = "https://www.autovit.ro/api/open/imageCollections"
wcapi = API(
        I wont show this, of course
        )

r = wcapi.get('products?category=1880')
r = r.json()
print("Request sent Successfull!")
#r_string=r.text


### Request de generare si capturare token client

url = "https://www.autovit.ro/api/open/oauth/token"

payload = """
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\n576\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\33333\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\npassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n55555\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n5555\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
"""
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "08d86f5e-fcdb-4fdb-a570-b044e1ce2a4a,98ba3d2d-7a6f-4eaf-9c85-4512febf51d5",
    'Host': "www.autovit.ro",
    'cookie': "PHPSESSID=8ppb0muarimpt14g10nnq9j6qi; user_id=3235571; id_token=eyJraWQiOiJDY3ZTY1ljRE5MS294RzRFMktPSTltcU5zczJxcmN4dENWaG5Xd2JYNlEwPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.HBalbgWl-EdXjQQT2NA1GkoVjapVixZ_YvREDCU6bEJhWrnXT2PLVE-5DN2uVdfwtI6uesTe4cn-x1MfyRD4g2JxPpaA11etDkjAqQeKckiQ5P2ubN4Kvb3HQvJLX_C-FG4B4PmbVTqXfljHgUFAHWZTJP742mGoI3tIZw7_yEgBaksS8Nwxihw3p6sPKygPuRSwQwDXfBNfP2oJYIgqhzdcT3Nnlc8-LBX5aIYA_CZdSyiU-D8I-nVHGR7JHKj5qXb2uVBP46KNIiH0Iq8HmgnpP4vjhio51va0v1LCLdtdGbm5rNbzGcZGf-zCKeCvf2L0EV9fqFmkOTbcEoOOXg; access_token=eyJraWQiOiJxSEl0RkdcL0ozKzNIVDd0aVR3dDZkYVVOQ2UwMzE0bXI2VGF3TDNWSEQ0UT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.OhSMdc54Ywgac_Qr5aVkuN_CkWQIa1TlFRyBqRedC_dAfk7kPLoUqUFPbvfvyczTsxu6wSkc4RRs5lR9HFSgaCrHNGyThd3GvFjuEAd8Ak2tqnNe9A7Ux77MYP0JAkbDUx94BJv3-wAwrRsIQCbSzbJa4VpObktl0ZzVTB34FUJ_4zuwquDGL0UN-Qq-Xhp0JdjJ3uu3okAyi3I52_cebuyuuFZmn1OpiRZyBc4BNT6zOhDfF5-1VuKLRtjFkWgsc7ENxVfmjnr1l5bATZX4XCD2wKTcjhs-IAldeS1JzUaZw5hsq1oR9rFGQ5u2BVvbY_TTlKkapGsOvBR1f1xM0g; refresh_token=eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.E_LEgltS3YUkrU1Z9xXeKbdAv0PDSgiRYms_ClyrDWkvcT8lBlm7fW77kG9BiJYtGNFUYLbA4psZdTFJI0W9w_QmQtIHLjYc4q3HjLgy8EqC9nHTaiCnpy5DLJy3FAcHxw-d8YGqaMEoV-5iqWypNBzqR-itGuzD57-q_EihRJFbyGstdyPHsFBOjww-LAPjmXmDWufHv8_Ha3nEgeWA3YQkmUy_9CEU14_RwUJeMrPeCRk9tylgRr_h1n_KOwXytjNw6GBs_I49YJotngEZCICNK6FL_czkOYkF4ylW8CHDBVybtxjzJcl5Bohl-RPBv_exl14fudwov1Fj_CXqZw.qiAGicVAAugBv0b4.LFIdBbSc0A6Hw6BjW_eBvgFCb6Nn0NeRVz4khxudzH_z490lPNYN_PDqQc_Sfj6kw8ESvb8tCjaDmQFnUZRRpfrX2DuTbgM_IpCJUVzoIP-2AZrXGi78jT-t_6zRwcv1Z51C2u6gaC7LGm4i2nuYYOr07ndE7Gjs1UHKN-A0E8I0ATx_GhSHT6r8Ld7US2CR4TSnF_X0_4L3jAcXS98Ru8vG5RNNs7tRS3EGwM31lWIqBVcI66R1q01KGLW291IqCdP8DeGRI10az9HnmXm4XxDZt10uT5GRgLqxLTu8pbgzCyL8yjSy6o7_j1h6lgWccb4zBwCRDnBr3ICHRvM7EjoMPkR91kBQmziw-XQTKcpWfvtNv8Dfwilq0lpbuezaVE7-fx9I54d66LrAW-QhyfMYAXaIEeKzxfrVB8pUXOzEAMfOuO0D-jfEKkttIMEonHZLNzl24Z1-gZo6XtcbviIaKw5nVlJyi_AUxzXUOURSE9QmzgdD6dGaU5J6ZBeHDdIcenGTceixArhBhvF9PV7WoWMlGv63G6gbtuV89NZ5cjr1GgjW-pmnfGuxv6Po0PxQAzY8AdDoK6pfAkn8L4gpAvMNbvC0PPVXV1OrfnaN7QsJ8yA-QEwdrENSml81JVdZZVMaHBMkrnkqHyH32eqES1PIORFgk-y7Ypi6WbScE9C-YPl1cOa8M3tnt2SaOod9x3_Q4qfi89_jb4MfBmIPZNltBVS3pZex2E5q53mL4NxAzes3XeIAog2jiSq-JsuAQt7f4p3-mFO4KpE7_18TAmZwbgzgHtQ0r10o2iqQQpYQzf3PIH5sOMi04aRSG4Q3LEzg_1nwLTZaW6O9aDklmuEgnKDEKyQW1BlW-LN5ICXEZovkMaOoU_luDomT7jYLRUY6v4CcmmnWDR2m7D84gA-3THEYJuR-aVxlnFsN5K6GGUEyETT17qK4ONqWMPR5w_GYenfV6N6tT_1rleHu1tjt5kAkCwU1o5oXhP4Q3hArJta7Par0xzM_I-whHI5ikrMHI83hrMu8nLSZ65h28gSc21ld94guaU-zCKIjvCo6gTqoGwbPd7yxopXSYYTqZ_-WPwDytITqf_Swj6GBG0yIiAu7-Zt10wmKgzfWARJECy4befAOiQMxReIuPaPC6kirEwyxMYXxq39WRqOfr-q_JjCrjyHugxPNmZaivFggfy9bqapScJK96-XHCTTyya78X-xmdu6VQjJiyE95G013aoau-X2-nkAswsOQhKDW2DR4EbRh2kO0yO8RRt8YU8a1OoED1W_mIuU2JvRJgUwGQnDiTFaL54w2GRrUSNVrL89s7MWnxg.vjAOfmEXwwfyOgFIW2Ti5Q; is_logged=1; newrelic_cdn_name=CF",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'content-length': "677",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

rresponse = requests.request("POST", url,data=payload, headers=headers)

req=rresponse.text
print(req)
json_data = json.loads(rresponse.text)
token=(json_data.get('access_token')) 

### End of first request



for i in r:
    titlu=(i.get('name'))
    cat_id="69"
    city_id="6613"
    lat="44.9578"
    longi="25.5688"

    tip="interior"
    body_type="hatchback"
    region_id="6"
    delivery="1"
    make="honda"
    manufacturer="Nespecificat"
    manufacturer_code="1234"
    pret=(i.get('price'))
    vat="1"
    advertiser_type="business"
    
    phone="0744000000"

    color="blue"
    engine_power="320"
    engine_capacity="1996"
    gearbox="manual"
    transmission="front-wheel"
    co2_emissions="177"
    person = "Multicom Auto"

    images = (i.get('images'))
    preview = images[0]


    imagine= (preview.get('src'))
    imagine2 = str(imagine)
    print(imagine2)

    payload4 =  "{\n    \"1\":  \""+imagine2+"\"\n}"
    headers4 = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token ,
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'Version': "2",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        'Postman-Token': "6f9f0c71-b854-4d7d-a7dd-a281b445eaef,868f6f2c-a87a-4e11-95e9-365972bb72ed",
        'Host': "ssl.autovit.ro",
        'cookie': "PHPSESSID=aq78pib4a5ei411mtvk7ts9jkq; user_id=3235571; is_logged=1; newrelic_cdn_name=CF",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'content-length': "99",
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
        }

    response4 = requests.request("POST", url4, data=payload4, headers=headers4)
    

    descriere=(i.get('description'))
    descriere2=descriere.replace("\n", "")
    descriere3=descriere2.replace('<div>', '')
    descriere5=descriere3.replace('</div>', '')
    

    print(titlu + " \n " +descriere5)

    json_id= response4.json()
    image_collection_id= (json_id.get('id'))
    print(response4)

    ### Start of Api POST Request

    

    headers2 = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'Version': "2",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        'Postman-Token': "04927f0a-cf06-4cb5-b83e-4eed29d1efec,829a1557-066a-4115-b134-66da62274203",
        'Host': "ssl.autovit.ro",
        'cookie': "PHPSESSID=iqfgqqgnbb15pk6ovt8bqvemm5; user_id=3235571; is_logged=1; id_token=eyJraWQiOiJDY3ZTY1ljRE5MS294RzRFMktPSTltcU5zczJxcmN4dENWaG5Xd2JYNlEwPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.HsKTCGiZ9rj9Tc9Bta8Eg-28XMnTOx5kzcuuFlV7DSPVAw9JH3zfSGK657RNE2SLMEt7CfYZwwUFAbgVXpEGci18kN1ekQj3CvzkPNigI_q8Lu4iQrt-cBJ72ZzZS5E7tYHZnsasB0mO4ZIZckILU0LjFwFVHTrt0M7ym9yCCYTCKdjZPJaIfbmIuv__RE1GDtWH2iazB19HvljOw4N2j8xnqFT0y0ZU-vGKckcTyhw_J7gnBasrzlGPRX60OIrcnJrfb53QHknfxbGqJYJjWSAhcVHWX7CZRse9vPKnjRVhxVL8qCfpf8GhITJARjg7cN_77j0OuXwa2s5bWlpEhg; access_token=eyJraWQiOiJxSEl0RkdcL0ozKzNIVDd0aVR3dDZkYVVOQ2UwMzE0bXI2VGF3TDNWSEQ0UT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.SrB8jc9gK-jZ4RL7EQEZmSYK2dmcvn7tEpHv6fz9UHoaj7421_ZaMyo1zJMwMYA0SOlYSOefesKpYINRUdKwinzVlSNtbbOKJc9CMZyjoIEIvCm0F-bdwK-jPGFbcFH7y2mQ3yzTNI0asJc7NO2QaXaO7pPM46L9IV10lBZYZ6sNDb6f6OjpPR9BipDpaLVRxH5h0QKgDHL1yY3NlpAqohvpD_6CKROMnLtpMO9GZ00fN_MxOM7BXb-H4M2TOxdc9HcLoCju80fMQ0HXWuOQMRUU4h5Of0j3B3qmCkubMza8k_uF7c2YAtbSb63I3INgkvQX5HaVMODA1E4ZkqWdpw; refresh_token=eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.a5LgkokKK_WUd3Yjk3_tZX-xy-oEhKLLiuXQbcEfa9GiMfzJB2yKvvnNwduH6VyA8OvPRJKByjDFWhu37Bli8Lf1RWAz1yd5s9m3Kxg2rDb6ECaQT96jy3y_jf_qTCF7S7t0NDxg6G8b5Gdk6Kwm5C20tnntr5-IVVxctsH0hEIVrKjVl3d84oA_sS67MoBPlgaF-NBZUOkL-kwzz3COSVSGziE2Hb9clh56ZxuK8uUcKD2xA0dD8i6wXujtwMzAOsdSuAZUZ3qkOG4yonNa9Sn9XV-L8FHIISLk0_KK9w2wGl9wXfoDbad7TnmfmmV2ujinK3HB3vIQdE7SQ7JXHw.eZS3I4UiaPbcOdbQ.fW8HX2tizpYWFE32nZhvZ1NufOTqhUQLfkx3Coh4tNk9TAECvYs8gEcx4GDBWTwohV7Kb1bLSPhbqQ7r1GdptWUt_Cru33hFX-BwTdh7BoBw18gKQjU5bfv0oYJ_izc-su63aNBz-yzKFxk06Gmj8qIjj9SrGGfLFlLgwTRP4-VtDn3pVxpkQ_jvKZfD8Mgj7_w0XkH3PZ-R9JuhWLSfIpzVicWL_oolx4NQEtNYGAHvc-nrb4Wcbp9v5uPfv0kS2t87Ofseus5_1ySMo-6O1whE84q95UzBvk36mkfWguaKFOOLmIGa4aFhJwgrBENleJuRxv5PCLt_gkGMoZr8y8V9kZEkdtYd2JHcrFwlkU20NPQc0GXNwWoFvAmb30C8ub0NgvV2KyxXENo0kvyxfXd4hwFeB1MgHJrHrvgh4axz8lOBul1depe2n6jJ5ogDSkxIKvX13O5Obqr6XtyV9DxIkXJoh3fXlMPYOjuu922PHf1yind8OPfA-dkt5M_T3ZF_EFHJ4znJmkpxi5-IO0zN9CVZSIEsNah56rFthcYO-GPbeF_eXT1V2iwnmLTuOz50_0qInOGcdL78SMomzYL4kJ9I7kWZQicbuTiNZu58fWSrcMLKGlqU3Oc0fm2RjBFyEy4XSgpcXr6k40MPqqxg7VIIgpvsKGIANiKrWtMlai_K6ZSR5ZDJvo3P74rE6F56tKDAq72bCXeSnBylrxTniPRXwk3gi_lHfzUgvPMnodgkI9NVMch0DZ_Pa4NbNLBfdh7aeR8sx7Vzfoz5wFVg9wuIwzSUp8A1JSha_KzcECY8GbEuaHfF1j6mF6R_Pue45BWlYyfBIz0J5zEPo9EXMqd4cWbrci7GhvEdeY6GGQTUUatwGNDVgz99hfmyf23AOAFu0w4IOgV7TlZvpt79vwBfJ0BDJwG-9ep1gM1tq7qLX_naTR6aWBN9d4KlILN52C9W2mWaMhGVTNST6I147L69lcITdjReuZPEuldE6mTl-W5TiTN1HHNbEBIRLRdd1XzLMlPbd1S6h8Ilwc6jYrt0GnWpnmMDJYOynoIv0A0eb-Loo79tVwjvfaUPuQDR7yBGT3Bwzec7RbVC6FQSI6BI1TlM0OeGW6eQ-gipjBV2CP9UF4HbcDWz2ZNOjNmlNwkqu63f4oxm1StyJRRHiPe0BPnVgBTtWrdli1dpM-d5YeTALNxowayUfPAiXb4Ih6MpGgnHYei2Tu5otVZz-jEEGeao0bG9Du7LHOtwd2C5OAw1hRS6NCC4QExETUjRWVk0vawLLDVTMVouRn6fXyKKBaM2kf1oc2td1J692mbyQCtmvmwNSw.65LsJCAJgfXFE6loW_JnsQ; newrelic_cdn_name=CF",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
        'content-length': "1062",
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
        }


    payload2 = "{\r\n   \"title\":\" "+titlu+" \",\r\n   \"category_id\":\" "+cat_id+" \",\r\n   \"region_id\": \" "+region_id+" \",\r\n   \"city_id\":\""+city_id+"\",\r\n   \"coordinates\":{\r\n      \"latitude\":\""+lat+"\",\r\n      \"longitude\":\""+longi+"\"\r\n   },\r\n   \"params\":{\r\n      \"type\":\""+tip+"\",\r\n      \"delivery\":\""+delivery+"\",\r\n           \"title\":\""+titlu+"\",\r\n      \"make\":\""+make+"\",\r\n      \"manufacturer\":\""+manufacturer+"\",\r\n      \"manufacturer_code\":\""+manufacturer_code+"\",\r\n      \"body_type\":\""+body_type+"\",\r\n      \"color\":\""+color+"\",\r\n      \"price\":{\r\n         \"0\":\"price\",\r\n         \"1\":"+pret+",\r\n         \"currency\":\"RON\",\r\n         \"gross_net\":\"gross\",\r\n      },\r\n      \"vat\":"+vat+",\r\n      \"engine_power\":\""+engine_power+"\",\r\n      \"engine_capacity\":\""+engine_capacity+"\",\r\n      \"gearbox\":\""+gearbox+"\",\r\n      \"transmission\":\""+transmission+"\",\r\n      \"co2_emissions\":\""+co2_emissions+"\"\r\n   },\r\n   \"description\":\""+descriere5+"\",\r\n   \"advertiser_type\":\""+advertiser_type+"\",\r\n   \"image_collection_id\":\""+image_collection_id+"\",\r\n   \"contact\":{\r\n      \"person\":\""+person+"\",\r\n      \"phone_numbers\":[\r\n         \""+phone+"\"\r\n      ]\r\n   }\r\n}"    
    
    url9 = "https://www.autovit.ro/api/open/account/adverts"

    headers9 = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer" +" "+ token,
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        }

    response9 = requests.request("GET", url9, headers=headers9)
    response9_json=response9.json()
    response9_txt=str(response9_json)

    if titlu in response9_txt:
        print("Anuntul a fost deja adaugat!")
    else:
        payload2_json=json.dumps(payload2)
        
        
        response2 = requests.request("POST", url2 ,json=payload2, headers=headers2)
        
        print(response2.text)
```

This script is just doing a bunch of requests, then creates ads on that website through api. However it has just stopped working suddenly, anyone has any idea why it gives me "BadRequestException","message":"Empty payload". Been trying to fix it all night long but it just wont work. I am thinking maybe its the guys that have the websites changed the api a bit or its an error somewhere? I tried sending payload as json, as utf8 but its not working anymore, no matter how hard i try

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: `payload2 = "{\r\n   \"title\":\" "+titlu+" ...` - please never do this. Create a proper dictionary and pass it to the request as such, it will serialize it for you. If you need it serialized, use `json.dumps(payload_dict)` instead. But never create json manually by joining strings together. I bet there will be the problem, as the result is very likely an invalid JSON. You can verify that yourself easily by trying to call `json.loads(payload2)`, you'll see it wont work.

Comment: There is not any traceback, just this response from the api: {"error":{"type":"BadRequestException","message":"Empty payload. Check if your payload is a valid JSON if applicable."}} it is reffering to payload2

Comment: Have you checked the API's documentation? Maybe it changed a bit and expects a different payload?

Comment: The documentation is very vague but nothing has changed there